# Testing out the Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We are interested in using Google's email services for our students, however we would like to test the API before acquiring the email services. Please say if there are any way to test the SDK without actually having to acquire the email services.

Thanks,
Amit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [signup for a 30 day trial](https://www.google.com/a/signup). Google won't charge you during this period. You can cancel before the end of the trial. You will have admin api access during this time.